# JS not applying new classes in CSS to HTML after comparing times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on an assignment for a coding class I'm in (very new to coding), and I am trying to apply colors to represent if a time block in this schedule app I'm making is in the past, present, or future. I've tried looking at some previous iterations of this project, and I have similar code, but the colors/classes are still not being applied. This is a chunk of my HTML that's serving as a time block:

```
<div id="nineAM" class="row time-block">
        <div class="col-md-1 hour">9 AM</div>
        <textarea class="col-md-10 input"></textarea>
        <button class="btn saveBtn col-md-1"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
     </div>
```

And here is what I have in JavaScript:

```
//Show current day in the header
var currentDate = $("#currentDay");
currentDate.text (moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY"));
//Current hour of the day
var currentHour = moment().format("HH");
//Comparing hour to time block displayed
function colorCode() {
    if (currentHour > 9) {
      $("#nineAM").addClass("past");
    } else if (currentHour >= 9 && currentHour < 10) {
      $("#nineAM").addClass("present");
    } else if (currentHour < 9) {
      $("#nineAM").addClass("future");
    }
};
```

(This is just one section of the function, it keeps going in a similar fashion until after 5pm).

And the CSS is simple, just like this:

```
.past {
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: white;
}
```

Instead of being dark gray, it's still the default white, and this is the same with my "past" class, which should be red, and my "future" class, which should be green. If there's anything else I need to show, please let me know!

Comment: What is `currentHour`? Where is it defined? Can you update your code such that it represents a complete [mre]?

Comment: Sorry about that! Just edited my question to include the beginning of the file with variable definitions.